# PostgreSQL. JOIN к массиву композитных типов

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица (`main_table`) с такими полями:

`id`, `custom_type[]`

custom_type создавался вот так:

`CREATE TYPE custom_type AS (param1 integer, param2 integer);`

Есть еще две таблицы, где `param1` это внешний ключ таблицы `foreign_table_1`, а `param2` таблицы `foreign_table_2`.

Как сделать так, чтобы к массиву custom_type можно было сделать JOIN эти двух таблиц?
Получается запрос должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT custom_type FROM main_table WHERE id = 1) AS t
    LEFT JOIN foreign_table_1 ON t.param1 = foreign_table_1.id
    LEFT JOIN foreign_table_2 ON t.param2 = foreign_table_2.id
```

У меня проблема в том, что не могу перевести массив в таблицу. То-есть делая запрос вот так:

```
SELECT t.param1 FROM (SELECT custom_type FROM main_table WHERE id = 1) AS t
```

получаю ошибку, что колонки t.param1 не существует.

Может есть какое-то другое решение, не используя композитный тип. Мне главное в `main_table` хранить массив из ключей `param1`, `param2`.

Answer (score 2):

Извлекать данные из композитных типов можно, если использовать круглые скобки.
Ваш запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
SELECT *
FROM   main_table AS t
       LEFT JOIN foreign_table_1 ON (t.custom_type).param1 = foreign_table_1.id
       LEFT JOIN foreign_table_2 ON (t.custom_type).param2 = foreign_table_2.id
WHERE  t.id = 1
```

В вашем решении я вижу по крайней мере два спорных момента:

1. На части составных типов не действуют ограничения целостности, следовательно, вы можете вставлять любые значения в таблицы ***foreign_table_1*** и ***foreig_table_2***, и postgres не будет автоматически проверять наличие этих ключей в композитном типе таблицы **main_table**.
2. Части композитного типа требуется индексировать отдельно. Если вы хотите, чтобы, к примеру, поиск ***param1*** или ***param2*** выполнялся с использованием индекса, придётся применять т. н. «вычисляемые индексы», и вешать их на ***param1*** и ***param2*** для поля ***custom_type*** в таблице ***main_table***.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос был решен вот так:

```
WITH Data AS (
    SELECT (unnest(custom_type)).* FROM main_table WHERE id=1
)
SELECT * FROM Data LEFT JOIN ...
```